# How to disable save write in the IDE "CodeAnyWhere"?

Tags: parceljs, codeanywhere

How to disable save write in the IDE **CodeAnyWhere**? - https://codeanywhere.com

Basically, save write is a feature that writes your changes in a new file and saves it, then deletes your old file and renames the new file to the same as the deleted file. This process makes ParcelJS confused, preventing the rebuild trigger to be executed. The feature prevents corrupted files in some scenarios.

Read this for more information on save write and the issue i have and why i ask this question on github and other sites:

1) https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/221
2) https://parceljs.org/hmr.html
3) https://medium.com/@pmarcus93/if-webpack-doesnt-rebuild-reload-your-project-on-code-changes-try-to-disable-safe-write-in-your-1de91fe6e053